# count where and if, within a select statement

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to write a stacked bar chart in mysql, and first I need to get the query right, and need some help.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT
COUNT(TargetDate) AS Planned,
COUNT(StartDate) AS Completed,
MONTHNAME(TargetDate) AS `Month`,
StartDate,
AssessmentStatus
FROM AuditCycleAssessments
WHERE (Year(TargetDate) = Year(now()))
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(TargetDate)
ORDER BY Month(TargetDate)
```

which works just fine and looks like [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/f8wh27)

However I need to change the 3rd line to include its own where statement, something like...

```
  (COUNT(StartDate) if AssessmentStatus=3) AS Completed,
```

So number 1, can someone help me achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

check how to write [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) But here you can not write if you should use CASE

```
SELECT
COUNT(TargetDate) AS Planned,
COUNT(CASE WHEN AssessmentStatus=3 THEN StartDate END) AS Completed,
MONTHNAME(TargetDate) AS `Month`,
StartDate,
AssessmentStatus
FROM AuditCycleAssessments
WHERE (Year(TargetDate) = Year(now()))
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(TargetDate)
ORDER BY Month(TargetDate)
```

Comment: This doesnt make sense. Because you are in a `GROUP BY` you are using a random `AssessmentStatus` to make the decision

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks I just go for if statement I have not check full query.

Comment: Probably you can check if can use IF inside the count. I use to CASE so that is what i go first.

Answer (score 1):

Do a conditional `COUNT` with a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT
    COUNT(TargetDate) AS Planned,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN AssessmentStatus=3 THEN StartDate END) AS Completed,
    MONTHNAME(TargetDate) AS `Month`,
    StartDate,
    AssessmentStatus
FROM AuditCycleAssessments
WHERE (Year(TargetDate) = Year(now()))
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(TargetDate)
ORDER BY Month(TargetDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might serve you, untested for your scenario it but it should work.

```
Sum(IIf([AssessmentStatus]=3 AND [StartDate] NOT IS NULL,1,0)) AS Completed,
```